# how to Create elastic search alias with limited fields from an Index?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, alias, elasticsearch-5

I have an Index with around 12 fields. for one of the client who wants to use our Index, we want to expose only 9 fields out of the 12 fields.

So finally we thought to go for creating an Alias and provide the access, But how can I exclude the other 3 fields from an index ?, where user should only be able to view/query on the 9 fields

thanks in advance